# Browser seems to cache DateTime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I realized that a change in system time is not immediately reflected in javascript, event if I use a new Date object. It is only updated every minute.

```js
var fakeElapsed = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 
    var oldTime = 0;
  
    function fakeTimeLoop(time){
    fakeElapsed+=(time-oldTime);
    oldTime = time;
      $("div").html(fakeElapsed);
   }
  
   var clock = new Date();
    var start = clock.getTime(); 
    oldTime = clock.getTime();
    setInterval(function(){
        var clock2 = new Date();
        var end = clock2.getTime();  
        var elapsed = end-start;
        if(elapsed%5===0){
          fakeTimeLoop(end);
        }},
        1
    );
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

Time code, if you would turn time forward (or backwards), it takes a minute to change the time elapsed.

Is there anyway to update to the system time every second?

Edit: for those who are confused, a change in system is not reflected immediately on Chrome and Opera, but on IE and Mozzila, it is immediately reflected, I assume its  order to avoid expensive system calls every time it needs to build a new Date object.

What I am looking for: is that anyway to get the current system time in chrome/opera or detect a change in system time immediately?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but your `setInterval` is programmed to execute every millisecond (the second parameter is in milliseconds), but [browsers treat any value less than 10 as equal to 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Even with that restriction, the timing isn't guaranteed to be exact, so the function may well execute every 11, 12, 13, etc. milliseconds.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. The setInterval is of no concern. I am trying to calculate the time elapsed of the system time, even if the user tries to do a time skip forward. Any idea?

Comment: Because `setInterval` isn't firing every millisecond, the conditional `if(elapsed%5===0)` is effectively random. Your calculation is correct, but the code that updates the HTML is only running sporadically.

Comment: Hi. I did realize that and I removed the per milkisecond conidition, it still does not immediately reflect change in system time immediately

Answer (score -1):

When you change your computer date/time and refresh the web page, `new Date()` will not return correct date/time. After 20-25 seconds it will return correct time. Probably it is a browsers' bug (I tested on Windows 10, Edge an Chrome).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).